# Клавиша с двойным нажатием в Java

Tags: java, eclipse, клавиатура

Возможно ли в Java сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на одну и ту же клавишу клавиатуры происходили разные действия. Например при нажатии клавиши `VK_F` воспроизводился аудио файл, а при повторном нажатии останавливался. Если возможно, то дайте пожалуйста пример кода.

Comment: да, это возможно

Comment: самое примитивное - создание флага boolean play = false;
при каждом нажатии play =!play что будет значит обратное значение.
свой проигрыватель уже привязываете к этому флагу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        private boolean isPlayed = false;

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F) {
                if (isPlayed) {
                    // выключить
                } else {
                    // включить
                }
                isPlayed = !isPlayed;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Объявляешь переменную

```
 private static boolean runStop = false;
```

Дальше в if else пишешь нужный код

```
                  btn.setOnAction((event) -> {

                            if (runStop == false) {
                                runStop = true;
                            //код для запуска
                            } 
                             else {
                                runStop = false;
                                //код для остановки  
                               }
                          }
                       );
```